# Update/insert lots of values on Pl/SQL

Tags: sql

I am a nood in PL SQL:

I want to insert lots of data in PL/SQL over PL/SQL Developer.

I set all the date in Nimble text and insert (cca 10.000 inserts)...
Then I execute queries...After a few minutes everything freeeze and I need to insert al most 500 inserts at once.

How can I insert/update that amount of data?

Tnx

Example of insert:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (130869,Name 1);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (085898,Name 2);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (151068,Name 3);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (110701,Name 4);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (113077,Name 5);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (059226,Name 6);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (137235,Name 7);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (133221,Name 8);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (136700,Name 9);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (053970,Name 10);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (120766,Name 11);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (081680,Name 12);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (150509,Name 13);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (127558,Name 14);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (100960,Name 15);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (089850,Name 16);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (114553,Name 17);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (011193,Name 18);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (094099,Name 19);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (093661,Name 20);
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ((130869,Name 1),(085898,Name 2),etc,etc)` in batches?

Comment: Inserting more that 500 rows takes forewer and often crash PL/Sql developer :(